# py2neo - Ne04j write instance

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am using the below code in Python to try connect to Neo4j.  However, when I run the code I get the error: "py2neo.database.status.Forbidden: No write operations are allowed on this database. This is a read only Neo4j instance.".

Does anyone know how I can create a write instance to Neo4j from py2neo?

```
import py2neo
from py2neo import Node, Relationship

g = py2neo.Graph('bolt://neo4j.het.io:7687', bolt=True)

tx = g.begin()
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
tx.create(a)
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
tx.create(ab)
tx.commit()
g.exists(ab)
```

Comment: Did you try authenticating the connection?

Comment: Yes, but  get the same error message.

Comment: Is your database on read-only mode ? Is it a cluster ?

Comment: How can I check if it is in Read only mode?

Answer (score 0):

`neo4j.het.io:7687` is a public, read only Neo4j instance.

Go to https://neo4j.com/download/ and download your own database, and change your script to hit `localhost:7687` instead.

(If you want that specific dataset, it is available for free -> https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet)